# why not running if statement tell me batch files

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

```
@echo off
@REM  **why not running if statement tell me:)**
set /P num1= "Enter your first number but don't enter 1, warning if you enter 1 you are hacked "
set /P num2= "Enter your second number but don't enter 1, warning if you enter 1 you are hacked "
echo num1 = %num1%
echo num2 = %num2%
set /A sum =%num1%+%num2%
if %sum% == 2 (
 goto start chrome-001 https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpOAe47k4uLjemSBTiAEk2g
 ) else (
echo Sum = %sum%
 )
 pause
@REM Thank you....
```

Comment: Just remove `goto`…

Comment: Why do you think, the `if` statement isn't running? The obvious problem here is that `goto` can't find a label `:start`. You should even get a message telling you.

Comment: BTW, ```set /A sum =%num1%+%num2%``` should really be ```Set /A sum = num1 + num2```.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but i don't really understood, can you give us the output in the cmd and explain a little bit?. Anyway, when using the 'Rem' command don't write '@REM' but only 'Rem comment'. Well, i guess the problem is that chrome doesn't open when giving the number '1' in all the inputs. The solution is simple, first replace these lines:

```
echo num1 = %num1%

echo num2 = %num2%
```

with these lines (if you want to echo the input):

```
echo %num1%

echo %num2%
```

I didn't quite understand what you were trying to do with those command lines but for sure you were getting an error.
Continue your code creating a new variable (for storing inside the broswer's name):

```
Set BROSWER=chrome.exe
```

**WARNING!** Put this variable code before opening the broswer.
Now the important part (opening the broswer), replace your lines:

```
if %sum% == 2 ( goto start chrome-001 https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpOAe47k4uLjemSBTiAEk2g ) else ( echo Sum = %sum% )
```

with these lines:

```
if %sum%==2 (start %BROSWER% -new-tab "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpOAe47k4uLjemSBTiAEk2g")ELSE(echo %sum%)
```

You did lot of errors with case sensitive and spaces, be careful. Hope i helped you, if not, leave a comment and i will try to re-edit my answer to help you.